# How do you identify the complexity of a pattern matching expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Pattern matching is *weird*. It involves the deceptively simple mathematical problem of finding a representation for a thing.

For example, for a given integer b, every integer a may be represented in the form a = bq + r, with 0 <= r < b, uniquely. To find the q and r requires the division algorithm. The key word being, "algorithm."

So when you perform a pattern matching express in Haskell, like representing a tuple as (a,b), is an algorithm running behind the scenes?

Must the algorithm always be simple, i.e. O(1) or documented somewhere somehow at least?

How do you guarantee a unique lift to a representation?

Comment: Pattern matching is a form of [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29), which in general is more complicated; however, in Haskell, we only have linear patterns and matching only works "in one direction", so there's much less complexity involved.

Comment: Pattern matching never "inverts" functions like multiplication, addition, etc. It works on the term algebra (a.k.a. free algebra, initial algebra), wherein we have _syntactic_ terms made by constructors, only, and patterns built from constructors and (linear) variables. So we need to solve equations such as `L x (K y) = L [2] (K (L 3))` which is done very simply in linear time wrt the size of the pattern. Essentially, to perform this you only need to examine the tip of the term which is being matched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what pattern matching actually does.

The machine stores all data in a fixed representation. Pattern matching merely allows you to query what that representation is.

You cannot use pattern matching to (for example) determine whether two arbitrary expressions are equivalent. That would require solving the Halting Problem, which is impossible. You can *only* pattern match on data, not expressions.

For example, pattern matching can tell you whether a list is empty or non-empty. It can tell you whether a list contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, in that order. It *cannot* tell you whether `sort . map fst` produces the same result as `map fst . sort`, for example.

So there is no problem of "guaranteeing a unique representation"; the computer already *does* that, whether you pattern match it or not. Pattern matching is O(n) time in the size of the pattern. (Ignoring any lazy evaluation you might trigger, which is a property of the code that produces the data, not the code that consumes it.)

Answer (score 7):

I may be misunderstanding what you are saying but there is an algorithm for pattern matching. From the [Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17):

> **3.17.2 Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching**
>
> Patterns are matched against values. Attempting to match a pattern can
>   have one of three results: it may fail; it may succeed, returning a
>   binding for each variable in the pattern; or it may diverge (i.e.
>   return ⊥). Pattern matching proceeds from left to right, and outside
>   to inside, according to the following rules:
>
> 1. Matching the pattern var against a value v always succeeds and binds
>      var to v.
> 2. Matching the pattern ~apat against a value v always
>      succeeds. The free variables in apat are bound to the appropriate
>      values if matching apat against v would otherwise succeed, and to ⊥ if
>      matching apat against v fails or diverges. (Binding does not imply
>      evaluation.) Operationally, this means that no matching is done on a
>      ~apat pattern until one of the variables in apat is used. At that
>      point the entire pattern is matched against the value, and if the
>      match fails or diverges, so does the overall computation.
> 3. Matching the wildcard pattern _ against any value always succeeds, and
>      no binding is done.
> 4. Matching the pattern con pat against a value,
>      where con is a constructor defined by newtype, depends on the value:
>      If the value is of the form con v, then pat is matched against v. If
>      the value is ⊥, then pat is matched against ⊥. That is, constructors
>      associated with newtype serve only to change the type of a value.
> 5. Matching the pattern con pat1 … patn against a value, where con is a
>      constructor defined by data, depends on the value: If the value is of
>      the form con v1 … vn, sub-patterns are matched left-to-right against
>      the components of the data value; if all matches succeed, the overall
>      match succeeds; the first to fail or diverge causes the overall match
>      to fail or diverge, respectively. If the value is of the form con′ v1
>      … vm, where con is a different constructor to con′, the match fails.
>      If the value is ⊥, the match diverges.
> 6. Matching against a constructor
>      using labeled fields is the same as matching ordinary constructor
>      patterns except that the fields are matched in the order they are
>      named in the field list. All fields listed must be declared by the
>      constructor; fields may not be named more than once. Fields not named
>      by the pattern are ignored (matched against _).
> 7. Matching a numeric,
>      character, or string literal pattern k against a value v succeeds if v
>      ==  k, where == is overloaded based on the type of the pattern. The match diverges if this test diverges. The interpretation of numeric
>      literals is exactly as described in Section 3.2 ; that is, the
>      overloaded function fromInteger or fromRational is applied to an
>      Integer or Rational literal (resp) to convert it to the appropriate
>      type.
> 8. Matching an as-pattern var@apat against a value v is the result of
>      matching apat against v, augmented with the binding of var to v. If
>      the match of apat against v fails or diverges, then so does the
>      overall match.

In the document I linked to, there is also a more formal description mentioned later.